# Scale font size when resizing UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I have a UITextView and its attributedText can have **different fonts, fonts sizes and colours** as shown in the image (left).

User can resize textView by dragging from resize handles (vertically/horizontally or diagonally). If user resize vertically, or horizontally I just change textView's width or height. **Nothing should happen to textView's font size**. If user resized diagonally (preserving aspect ratios) I want to **proportionally scale font size** of each text range (should look like right image).

Please note that I resize the textView by changing its width and height constraints(not using scale transformations).

[image]

Here is how I proportionally scale font size of each text block when I resize the textView.

```
            let attributedText = self.textView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            attributedText.beginEditing()
            
            // change the size of any font found in the attributed string
            attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.string.utf16.count)) { (value, range, stop) in
                if let oldFont = value as? UIFont {
                    let newFont = oldFont.withSize(oldFont.pointSize * scaleX)
                    attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
                }
            }
            attributedText.endEditing()
            self.textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

So as you can see, if textView width got doubled (ie `scaleX = 2`), then font's point size also get doubled. But I'm not sure whether that is correct, because sometimes text content become larger than the textView size. Thus some texts get clipped by the textView bounds.

There are several stackoverflow questions about how to resize font size to fill UITextView. But that's not exactly I want.

How can I calculate the correct scale factor that I should use to scale font size?

Comment: Start by defining what you want. I'd keep a "initial size" (for webviews and fonts). I'll use the factor being the `min(newWidth/oldWith, newHeight/oldHeight)`, meaning, if only width is changed, font size don't change, same if it's only height. I's the main idea, might need to edges fixes.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my question is clear. Actually I can calculate the scale factor (scaleX and scaleY) correctly for uitextView. But same scale factor seems to be not correct for scaling fonts. That's what I meant.

Comment: I meant that I wouldn't change the font size if only width or if only height did change. I'd use the factor only if both did change. My comment wasn't about "being able to calculate", but more about the logic on when/what calculate. If you change the font size, if won't be "it's only scaling on X or on Y", it's a "both x-y scale". Else it might be need to use CoreText if you want to "stretch" the text.

Comment: Yes of course. May be my explanation is bad. Actually I'm not changing font size when scaling vertically or horizontally. Currently I change font size only when scaling is done diagonally (ie when both width and height change).